# Python como crear un archivo excel con todas las columnas de varios ficheros

Tags: python, excel

quiero crear un fichero excel que contenga todas las columnas de varios ficheros (todos los archivos excel de un directoro) y al utilizar el comando "merge" suma el contenido y no me sirve. Hay otra opción de "merge" que une dos dicheros añadiendo un sufijo en las columnas pero al ser mas de dos ficheros me falla tambien

Que comando o linea tendría que usar?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para combinar múltiples archivos de Excel en uno solo, manteniendo todas las columnas y sin sumar el contenido, puedes utilizar la biblioteca pandas en Python. Por otro lado, para combinar los ficheros que dices, puedes concatenar los dataframes:

```
 import pandas as pd  
 archivos = ["archivo1.xlsx", "archivo2.xlsx","archivo3.xlsx"]  
 dataframes = []  for archivo in archivos:  
 dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(archivo))
 dataframe_combinado = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1, sort=False,  ignore_index=True) 
 dataframe_combinado.to_excel("archivo_combinado.xlsx")
```

Asegúrate de que todos los archivos de Excel que deseas combinar tengan la misma estructura de columnas. Si las estructuras de las columnas son diferentes, el código no funcionará correctamente.

Comment: Recuerda que estas usando Python, es importante la indentación.  te sugerimos revisar [answer] y también [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.